# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in dataTask

Tags: swift

I am converting my code to swift 3 but getting "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error in the following code .

```
open class func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            completion(data, response.statusCode,error)
        })
    }
    task.resume() 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler wants `Error` not `NSError`.

Further in Swift 3 omit the parameter labels in the completion handler and don't pass IUO* parameters if you actually mean non-optional:

```
open class func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, Int, Error?) -> Void) {
```

Finally you don't need an `URLRequest` in this case, GET is the default, so just pass the URL to `dataTask` and delete the two lines related to the request.

(*) Implicit Unwrapped Optional

Answer (score 1):

There is two problem in your code first `response.statusCode`, response is type of [`URLResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlresponse) and it doesn't have property `statusCode` so you need to type cast it to [`HTTPURLResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse) to get the [`statusCode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse/1409395-statuscode). Second is from Swift 3 use native `Error` instead of `NSError`, So your whole code would be like this.

```
open class func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode,error)
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```